# How to restore from a .bak file in Azure Data Studio for Mac

Tags: sql-server, macos, azure-data-studio

I'm trying to use Azure Data Studio for Mac, I need to restore a databse using a .bak file, I have that file in finder, but when I click restore I click on "Restore from" choose Backup file, then "Backup File path" click on "..." but it never open the explorer to browse the file.

[image: Backup File path window"]

I can't realize how to use this, can you please help me with this?

Comment: You don't "browse" a backup file, you restore it onto a SQL Server instance. If your using a Mac that'll either be the instance you're running in Docker, or on a remote host (not running OS X).

Comment: yes, this is a SQL Server instance I'm running in Docker. I need to use a .bak file I have in a share directory I can access through finder in Go menu >> Connect to server, is there a way to do this?

Comment: So you can see the file from Docker? Your SQL Server Instance is running in a container, it can't "see" the same things you can on your host OS. YOu need to copy the backup file to the container: [Copy a backup file into the container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/tutorial-restore-backup-in-sql-server-container?view=sql-server-2017#copy-a-backup-file-into-the-container) (or map the share on Docker as well).

Comment: Using the link you provided I was able to solve the issue, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I know the answer. You have to upload to docker to .bak file.

Type the following code into the terminal and run:

docker cp ~/Downloads/"sqlfiles[image]"/ETRADE2.bak CONTAINER ID:/var/opt/mssql/data

Later on, you can restore file like windows